# Does the --hide-my-port option reduce traffic?

Tags: monerod, full-node, aeon, bandwidth

While trying to maintain a local full Monero or Aeon node with limited bandwith available, does the `--hide-my-port` option reduce traffic (even if no port forwarding is enabled at the router)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--hide-my-port` option is used to prevent incoming connections of peers to your node, which would reduce traffic if your node could receive incoming connections.

But if your node is behind a router without port forwarding, it already can't receive incoming connections, therefore the `--hide-my-port` option won't have any extra effect on traffic reduction.